# Runtime.exec not running cd

Tags: java, ioexception

**Runtime.getRuntime().exec()**

The former does not work when I pass it the command "cd filename"
full code;

```
package com.piomnicron.riles;

import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class A {
protected static Runtime B = Runtime.getRuntime();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File E = new File("");
    System.err.println(E.getAbsolutePath());
    try{
        B.exec("cd "+E.getAbsolutePath()+"\\");

    }catch(Throwable e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "had an oopsie!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

My question happens to be, why does it throw the following IOException:

```
cannot run program "cd": CreateProcess error = 2, The system could not find the file specified
```

I tried it without the +"\" first in case anyone thinks that might be the answer,

I *have* done some Googling, and none of the answers i found answer my question in any way, they all focus on opening a jar, or file, but I just want to know why the cd command doesn't work. I cannot use an absolute path for the cd because that means it will break if someone moves the folder it's contained in.

the error is the B.exec(); part in case you were wondering

*Please excuse any grammatic errors, the sun is in my eyes and I can barely see the screen.*

Comment: What are you trying to do by running `cd` using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`?  Are you trying to change the current directory of the Java class you're running (`A`)?

Comment: @LukeWoodward No, I am trying to get the command to run there, I actually _am_ trying to run a jar file, but using `B.exec("java -jar PotatoScript.jar");` [Don't Ask]

Comment: What do you think the result of executing that `cd` would be? Put the command(s) in a `.bat` (or `.cmd`) file and then you could exec that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't (usefully) issue a `cd` command through `Runtime.exec`. The `cd` command, on most OS's, is a built-in command of the shell, not an executable (which is why you get the error you get), and it operates on the runtime environment of the shell. Although you *could* use `Runtime.exec` to fire up a shell and execute the `cd` command within it (for Windows that would be `cmd.exe /c "cd path"`), it would only change the current directory *within the shell*, not for the program running.

What you need to do is resolve the directory within your program, using the various features of `File`, and use that resolved absolute file path for whatever it is that you're trying to use `cd` for.

If you post a (new) question saying what it is you're trying to achieve by using `cd`, we can help you achieve that, but using `Runtime.exec` to issue `cd` isn't going to be the solution.